# ROS2 Multicast - can't see any topics

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm running ROS2 Dashing on my Raspberry Pi inside a docker container (Balena) on Ubuntu 18.04, here are the packages installed:

```
ros-dashing-ros-base  
ros-dashing-slam-toolbox   
ros-dashing-navigation2   
ros-dashing-nav2-bringup
```

I'm running only one node at the moment - `rplidar` which publishes `LaserScan` data to `/scan` topic.

Here is how I start the process:

```
source /opt/ros/dashing/setup.bash; source ./install/setup.bash; ROS_DOMAIN_ID=45 ros2 launch rover rover.py
```

Then I'm trying to get a list of nodes on my Ubuntu machine running ROS2 Eloquent (maybe this is the problem?):

```
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=45 ros2 node list
```

which gives me

```
/launch_ros
/rplidar
```

So far so good.
But when I'm trying to get a list of topics I get only the default ones:

```
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=45 ros2 topic list

/parameter_events
/rosout
```

Is there a step I'm missing?
I followed the "Troubleshooting" section here: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Troubleshooting/  and multicasting are enabled on both Ubuntu PC and on Raspberry Pi.
The fact that I can see remote nodes is also encouraging.

Is it just version incompatibility or I really need to run the same version on Raspberry Pi and Ubuntu?

Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345407/ros2-multicast---can%27t-see-any-topics/) by [Leonti](https://answers.ros.org/users/51710/leonti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2020-02-28

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was the incompatibility between Dashing and Eloquent which makes sense.
After compiling Dashing on my Ubuntu 19.10 and running:

```
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=45 ros2 topic list --spin-time 30
```

I can now see

```
/parameter_events
/rosout
/scan
```

I'm also able to visualise the scan data with Rviz:

```
ROS_DOMAIN_ID=45 rviz2
```

---

Originally posted by [Leonti](https://answers.ros.org/users/51710/leonti/) with karma: 62 on 2020-02-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0